# Javascript GetElementsByClassName Variable Position

Tags: javascript, vb.net, getelementsbyclassname

Will try to make this as succinct as possible.

Using a browser control in VB.Net to run Javascript to loop through through elements on a webpage.

I have it *mostly* working and this would solve my last weeks worth of problems I'd really appreciate a pointer here.

So far:

```
    Dim s As String = browser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByTagName('li').length")

    If s <> "undefined" Then

        Dim iCount As Integer = CInt(s)

        For i As Integer = 0 To iCount - 1

            Dim classcounter As String = browser.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere').length")

            Dim iCount2 As Integer = CInt(classcounter)

            For i2 As Integer = 0 To iCount2 - 1
                MsgBox(BetfairCSControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[0].textContent"))
                MsgBox(BetfairCSControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[1].textContent"))
                MsgBox(BetfairCSControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[2].textContent"))
            Next


        Next
    End If
```

This works. It loops through the li tags and gives me the data I was expecting. The amount of results can vary however and I thought something like this would work:

```
  For i2 As Integer = 0 To iCount2 - 1
            MsgBox(BetfairCSControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[i2].textContent"))
        Next
```

I'm just replacing the hard coded integer with a variable. I thought that would of been the easy part.

But it shows me undefined. Even if I give it a variable which is an integer at 0, 1 or 2 it shows undefined. [0] works but testcounter = 0 and [testcounter] doesn't.

Please someone tell me this is an easy syntax issue or something? If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: It's not the IE browser control it's a third party. Textcontent seems to work fine it gives me exactly the data I would expect. My issue is I have to give it [0] [1] [2] etc... rather than being able to give it [i] in a loop and getting every result it has. Thanks though appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about VB.net, but shouldn't you concatenate

```
"document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[" + i2 + "].textContent"
```

Otherwise you'll just end up with this exact string

```
"document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[i2].textContent"
```

without replacing the i2 with it's actuall

```
MsgBox(BetfairCSControl.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult("document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[i2].textContent"))
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is Javascript which is a pretty new area for me. I'm sure my problem is with giving it this [i2] or any variable for that matter. I tried [" + i2 + "] and it didn't display anything at all. Didn't even throw an exception which is strange I guess it can't handle javascript exceptions being used.

Comment: I believe that will not compile with `Option Strict On` and will throw and except when run if compiled with `Option Strict Off`. It is best to convert `i2` to a String before concatenating with other Strings, and to use the VB String Concatenation operator &. `"document.getElementsByClassName('classnamehere')[" & i2.ToString & "].textContent"`

Comment: The two of you have just solved my problem and put the nail in the coffin of the issues I've been having for almost a week now. Thank you both very much.